# .net how to download the excel document

Tags: .net, excel, interop, office-interop

I created an excel document like this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;




 protected void excelExport(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel._Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;
                workSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "Received Calls";
}
```

when i run my code, i got excel opening with the data that i want, but now i want to download the document (not openeing it)

what should i do please?

>

i already tried to do

```
workSheet.SaveAs("asdfasdf");
```

but that will open the doc and saves it, but i need to just download it without opening it

#### Updtea

I find this

```
 excelApp.GetSaveAsFilename(nameOfDocument, "Excel Filter (*.xlsx), *.xlsx");
```

but when i run it, a file selector (to select the name of the file) is open, when i click save, nothing is being saved,

what am i missing please?

Answer (score -1):

Are you using it in a web application since you are mentioning it is a download?

If so you are better of using the [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx), maybe even combined with [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

With that you can use the following code to download an excel file

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/Excel";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExcelFile.xlsx");
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
     wb.SaveAs(memoryStream);
     memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
     Response.Flush();
     Response.End();
}
```

Comment: also what is wb? (copying codes from internet is not a good thing)

Comment: it's just a snippet, wb stands for the workbook and is of type XLWorkbook